# Calling Event Handler from Enter key wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events, syncfusion

Id like to know how to call an event handler from an enter key.

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter){

SearchButton_Click(sender, e);
}


private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

EDIT: Since i got the answer of this initial question, id like to add more.
Using enter key and click button, that calls the same method, gives me two different output.

I have a boolean value that checks true or false if there are errors.

With click button, i get a true when there are errors in the search and with the Enter key i get false when there are errors, and it call the same method within the same event handler

Any tip?

Using WPF XAML and Syncfusion validator, can it be the cause

Comment: try making your button as default ?

Comment: `if(e.Key == VirtualKeys.Enter) SearchButton_Click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());` ?

Comment: if you just want a button to react on enter, make it default

Comment: Edited the initial question, thanks for the answers, this solve my part 1